# Laravel Socialite - Upgrade Twitch scopes

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-socialite

I'm developing web app with Laravel stack on back server and NuxtJS on front server. I already use Socialite with `socialiteprovider/twitch` to sign user in stateless and all works fine.

Now the problem is, I need to upgrade the user's scopes when he push a button on front. When he is authenticated, I have to store `oauth_token` and `refresh_token` in database to make Twitch API's call later, but I don't know how to do that...

Which process i should use ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot update the scope of an already existing authentication token even if you refresh the token, the scope in the refresh must be the same scope or be omitted. So you have to authenticate the user with the new scope.

Comment: glad I could help ✌

Comment: Thx for your help :D